# How to get Tailwind CSS to config file to connect to my HTML?

Tags: html, tailwind-css, implementation

I'm trying to use custom colors in the my html file but by tailwind.config.js does not seem to be connecting. I have the content configured to './*.html' so it'll look for everything in the root. My HTML file is in my root so anyone know what is wrong?

````
```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./*.html'],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: "480px",
      md: "768px",
      lg: "976px",
      xl: "1440px"
    },
    extend: {
      brightRed: "hsl(12, 88%, 59%)",
      brightRedLight: "hsl(12, 88%, 69%)",
      brightRedSupLight: "hsl(12, 88%, 95%)",
      darkBlue: "hsl(228, 39%, 23%)",
      darkGrayishBlue: "hsl(227, 12%, 61%)",
      veryDarkBlue: "hsl(233, 12%, 13%)",
      veryPaleRed: "hsl(13, 100%, 96%)",
      veryLightGray: "hsl(0, 0%, 98%)",
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add it into a colors section. Changing it to this should fix your problem.

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./*.html'],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: "480px",
      md: "768px",
      lg: "976px",
      xl: "1440px"
    },
    colors: {
      brightRed: "hsl(12, 88%, 59%)",
      brightRedLight: "hsl(12, 88%, 69%)",
      brightRedSupLight: "hsl(12, 88%, 95%)",
      darkBlue: "hsl(228, 39%, 23%)",
      darkGrayishBlue: "hsl(227, 12%, 61%)",
      veryDarkBlue: "hsl(233, 12%, 13%)",
      veryPaleRed: "hsl(13, 100%, 96%)",
      veryLightGray: "hsl(0, 0%, 98%)",
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

From there you can specify different versions. Like 100, 200, 300 by adding something like this.

```
      'tahiti': {
        100: '#cffafe',
        200: '#a5f3fc',
        300: '#67e8f9',
        400: '#22d3ee',
        500: '#06b6d4',
        600: '#0891b2',
        700: '#0e7490',
        800: '#155e75',
        900: '#164e63',
      },
```

This is all off of the tailwind documentation [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors)
Hope this helps